# Hash для запоминания url

Tags: php, хеширование

Hash для идентификации url?

Нужно запоминать некоторые URL, посещенные пользователем на сайте, для того, чтобы в случае необходимости вернуть пользователя на этот адрес. Например, пользователь зашел на страницу `example.com?part=cart&order=1` (корзина с заказами), в БД записался адрес этой страницы и вернулся hash этого адреса, например `5f41402dbc4b2a76b9231d911017c592`. Для каждой ссылки на товар заказа к адресу ссылки добавляется параметр backurl. Т.е., чтобы отредактировать товар из корзины, ссылка на него получается такого вида:

```
example.com?part=goods&id=57483&backurl=5f41402dbc4b2a76b9231d911017c592
```

Теперь после любых действий с этим товаром, по нажатию кнопки "сохранить" пользователь будет возвращен на страницу с хешем

```
5f41402dbc4b2a76b9231d911017c592: example.com?part=cart&order=1.
```

Какой hash лучше использовать в этом случае? Чем он меньше (короче) - тем лучше, предполагаю использовать md5 - его длина 32 символа, а криптостойкость большого значения не имеет, так как шифруется не пароль, а только адрес ссылки + пользователь не сможет перейти по ссылке другого пользователя, так как в БД с хешем записывается еще идентификатор пользователя. Хотелось бы что-то наподобие  `tinyurl.com`

Comment: А почему не использовать автоинкрементный идентификатор из базы?

Comment: Потому, что не хочется "светить" кол-во ссылок, их рост и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи адреса ссылки воспользовался советом @Anton Shchyrov (использовать автоинкрементный идентификатор из базы), только с некоторыми дополнениями: цифровой id скрывается при помощи [Hashids](http://hashids.org/php/). Выглядит уже намного лучше:

```
example.com?part=goods&id=57483&backurl=ObA1k253
```

Hashids позволяет не только закодировать id, но и произвести обратную операцию расшифровки, поэтому такие хеши не нужно хранить в БД.

Для проверки на дубли (чтобы не писать в БД дубли одинаковых ссылок) я решил использовать hash md5. Шанс словить коллизию, когда 2 разных ссылки будут иметь идентичный хеш md5 - минимален и стремится к нулю.

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите метку времени (timestamp). Они будут уникальными и не требуют какого-то сложного механизма генерации. Вот так можно получить миллисекундный stimestamp:

```
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Comment: Timestamp, на сколько я помню, записывается с точностью до секунд? Если так, то вероятность того, что появятся дубли довольно высока

Comment: есть разные timestamp. есть которые записывают с точностью до миллисекунд. я добавил код в ответ.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, возьму на заметку.

Comment: @Miron Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Если бы он был исчерпывающий - я бы так и сделал :)

Comment: скажите как улучшить ответ? чем данное решение не подходит? вы можете отметить и свой ответ.